# Retrieve related model querying with a pivot table column value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a **Employee** Model that has a pivot table **customer_employee** (employee_id, customer_id, token) accessed through the belongsToMany relationship **agents()**:

```
class Employee extends Model {
    ...
    public function agents(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('token');
    }
```

and I want to query (in Eloquent) de database to obtain the Employee model whose agent's token == 'abc'.

Can anyone help me? Thanks and regards.

(1) **token** and **(employee_id, customer_id)** are unique

(2) In raw sql would be

```
$sql = 'select employee.*
        from employee inner join customer_employee
        on employee.id = customer_employee.employee_id
        where customer_employee.token = "abc"';
```

Comment: Hi, in documentation please read about #Has One Through and #Has Many Through. That should help.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Laravel join the pivot table on whereHas so you could try something like this:

```
        Employee::whereHas('agents', function ($query) {
            $query
                ->where('customer_employee.token', 'the_token');
        })->first();
```

You could also try with a custom relationship using [wherePivot][1]

```
public function agents($token): BelongsToMany
            {
                return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('token')->wherePivot('token', $token);
            }
```

Also your model is Employee, and your agent relationship is also Employee. Should the model be Customer?
[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer [Mtxz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5608694/mtxz). I am first trying your second option, but I do not know how to call it. If I do `$result = Employee::agents('the_token')` I obtain the error: **Non-static method App\Models\Employee::agents() cannot be called statically**. If I create an auxiliary variable `$aux = new Employee;` and then `$result = $aux->agents(''the_token'');` returns a null value.

Comment: I think I made a mistake: my second example will only query 1 agent with a belonging Employees where token. Not all Employees match your token rule. So you should use the first solution, which is anyway the best.

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much!